# Watermark TextBox in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox, watermark

What is the easiest way to implement watermark textbox control in ASP.NET MVC, are there any such controls on the internet (codeplex maybe).
I suppose it is quite simple to write one extending HtmlHelper and using jquery watermark textbox implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Jquery plugin like the following:

[Watermark Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/updnWatermark)

There is a sample provided and is simple to use.

Comment: Stick with JQuery over AJAX Control

Comment: That link is broken.  I believe the correct link is http://plugins.jquery.com/watermark/

Answer (score 0):

I would use this one: http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/

Comment: This plugin doesn't fit so well with validation plugins unfortunately as it works by setting the value of the input control, whereas the one for the accepted answer creates an overlay span.

Comment: Thanks mdresser. I'll have a look at that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TypedTextBox of my Mvc Controls toolkit here: http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TypedTextBox

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend ClearField jQuery plugin:  http://labs.thesedays.com/projects/jquery/clearfield/

It's very simple to use as shown here (copied & pasted from link above):

Put this in your HTML pages header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.clearfield.js"></script>
```

Add this function somewhere on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clearField').clearField();
});
```

Your input field might look like this:

```
<input type="text" class="clearField" value="What's your name?" />
```

If you were using with ASP.NET (not MVC), you'd possibly be using an ASP control like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Search" runat="server" CssClass="clearField">Search Something</asp:TextBox>
```

For the part where it say's "Add this function somewhere on the page", you'd want to make sure it's within script tags like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.clearField').clearField();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568476/watermark-for-mvc3-razor-using-displayprompt/10660821#10660821)

with this jquery you can show watermark on your text box .Here I am using an image in place of watermark.You need to create an image of the watermark text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            /*Watermark for date fields*/

             if ($("#dob").val() == "") {
                $("#dob").css("background", "#ebebeb url('/Content/images/DateWaterMark.png') no-repeat 1px 0px");
            }

            $("#dob").focus(function () {
                if (watermark == 'MM/DD/YYYY') {
                    $("#dob").css("background-image", "none");
                    $("#dob").css("background-color", "#fff");
                }
            }).blur(function () {
                if (this.value == "") {
                    $("#dob").css("background", "#ebebeb url('/Content/images/DateWaterMark.png') no-repeat 1px 0px");
                }
            });

            $("#dob").change(function () {
                if (this.value.length > 0) {
                    $("#dob").css("background", "#fff");
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use the [AJAX Control Tookkit Watermark](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx) control.